# Response cards in aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to create a chatbot that uses response cards in one of its slots. I want to try updating the response cards on AWS lambda instead of in amazon lex since I do not want the image in the cards.  But when I try running it, it gives off an error "Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled". The slot that I want to have the response cards is the Sector slot. Is there something wrong with my code?

[image]

Below is my code.

```
def multiply(intent_request):

    invoice = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['Invoice'])
    advance = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['CashAdvance'])
    datedue = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['DueDate'])
    sector = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['Sector'])

    session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}

    last_confirmed_loan = try_ex(lambda: session_attributes['lastConfirmedLoan'])
    if last_confirmed_loan:
        last_confirmed_loan = json.loads(last_confirmed_loan)
    confirmation_context = try_ex(lambda: session_attributes['confirmationContext'])

    loan = json.dumps({
        'Invoice': invoice,
        'CashAdvance': advance,
        'DueDate': datedue,
        'Sector': sector
    })

    session_attributes['currentLoan'] = loan


    if intent_request['invocationSource'] == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # Validate any slots which have been specified.  If any are invalid, re-elicit for their value
        validation_result = validate_loan_details(intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])
        if not validation_result['isValid']:
            slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
            slots[validation_result['violatedSlot']] = None

            return elicit_slot(
                session_attributes,
                intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                slots,
                validation_result['violatedSlot'],
                validation_result['message']
            )

        if sector is not None:    
            return {
                'dialogAction': {
                    'type': 'elicit_slot',
                    'fulfillmentState': 'ElicitSlot',
                    'message': {
                        'contentType': 'PlainText',
                        'content': 'What sector?'
                    },            
                    'responseCard': {
                      "version": 3,
                      "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
                      "genericAttachments": [
                        {
                          "title": "Company Sectors",
                          "subtitle": "Select one",
                          "buttons": [
                            {
                              "text": "Company A",
                              "value": "32"
                            },
                            {
                              "text": "Company B",
                              "value": "33"
                            },
                            {
                              "text": "Company C",
                              "value": "34"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                }
            }

        session_attributes['currentLoan'] = loan
        return delegate(session_attributes, intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])


    logger.debug('LoanDetails under={}'.format(loan))

    try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('currentLoan'))
    session_attributes['lastConfirmedLoan'] = loan

    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Multiply can purchase your invoice at $' + invoice + ' for a fee of $_________, are you down for it?'
        }
    )
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? on what utterance? please give examples

Comment: It gives off an error "Invalid Lambda Response", after the Sector slot. I've updated my question with the following details

Comment: have you checked CloudWatch error logs for your Lambda function? you might be getting detailed log there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [response structure documented for Amazon Lex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html).  It looks like your usage of dialogAction "type" and "fulfillmentState" are not correct.

**Type** can be set to:

- Close
- ConfirmIntent
- Delegate
- ElicitIntent
- ElicitSlot (not "elicit_slot" as you have)

**fulfillmentState** can be set to:

- Fulfilled
- Failed

fulfillmentState should be used when type is set to Close.
There may be other syntax issues, but those stand out.